# programming algorithm: how evenly distribute categories across columns

Tags: algorithm

I have a number of categories each category has a number of elements. I'm now looking for a programming algorithm to distribute these categories across a predefined number of columns without breaking up the categories, keeping the category order, and keeping the number of elements in each column as optimal as possible.

For example:
Distribution 5 categories across 3 columns

```
Data:
category A, 7 elements
category B, 7 elements
category C, 3 elements
category D, 2 elements
category E, 8 elements
```

Outcome:

```
Column 1: category A, 7 elements
Column 2: category B and C, 10 elements
Column 3: category D and E, 10 elements
```

Comment: How do you define optimal? How large are you data (is brute force an option)?

Comment: The definition of most optimal I think is where the sum of the difference between elements per column and total elements divided by the number columns is as small as possible. I think brute force is an option I expect maybe 100 columns and 1000 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the total number of elements, so you can divide that number by the number of columns to get the expected number of elements in each column. Your job is then to minimize the sum of the squares of the differences (so, if you have to store 8 elements and you store 10, you have a squared difference of 2² = 4 for that column).

You can then write a recursive function that, for every category, decides whether to move that category to the next column, or keep it in the current column. This is a boolean decision, so you can start by the branch that creates the smallest difference, and then the branch that creates the largest. The function would keep track of the best solution found so far, and immediately stop if the current sum of squared differences is greater than the total for that solution.

Comment: What is the idea behind the squares?

Comment: With linear differences, nine perfect columns and one column off by 10 would be equivalent to ten columns off by one. Square differences penalize wildly differing column values, so the errors end up being spread evenly.

Comment: Got it to work, however I did it brute force calculating the sum of the squares for each combination. It now runs on php, it's not lighting fast but if used with less than 100 categories it should suffice.